# What just happened to "Review"?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

Recently, I just noticed that the review option on many sites broke, resulting in [image: this]

However, it does not affect this site and stackoverflow. What has happened?

Comment: I can confirm this happened on Travel SE too.

Comment: Happened on chem.SE too.

Comment: Just take a look at [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22094840#22094840)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can't reproduce this, you guys must be crazy. Or the SQL query was bad for a few minutes. But I'm going with users be cray cray.

Comment: Nevermind, it is fixed now. Go delete this question